# Cookie to remember modal window choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I have a modal popup made in javascript where you can choose the language of a website, English or French. When you click English it'll load an English HTML page, and French it'll just remove the modal popup. How can I create a cookie to remember the choice of the user, so the modal is hidden until the cookie expires? I've come across the jQuery-cookie, but I don't know how to combine it with that onclick function I've created in Javascript. Any tips?

Javascript

```
function langMessage() { 

   this.messageBox = null;

   this.popOut = function(messageText, en_lang, fr_lang) {

   var english = document.createElement("div");
   english.className = "english";
   english.innerHTML = en_lang;
   this.messageBox.appendChild(english);

   english.onclick = function() {
      window.location.href = "test-en.html";
   }

   var french = document.createElement("div");
   french.className = "french";
   french.innerHTML = fr_lang;
   this.messageBox.appendChild(french);

   french.onclick = function() {
      this.parentNode.Code.remove();
   }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var message = new langMessage();
        message.popOut("Please choose your preferred language", "English", "French");
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you get too enthusiastic about this, read up on the "accept-language" attribute of an HTTP request. Essentially you can pick up which language the user prefers from the request, as a starting point anyway.

It's not an absolute guide to which language should be used, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's a design choice to let the user choose himself with the modal window. But thanks for the useful information, perhaps it'll be a choice of mine another time.